# Can't get display resolution for all devices using EnumDisplaySettings

Tags: c, windows, winapi, gdi

I need to get the current display resolution of all monitors attached to the computer.

I can succesfully enum the display devices using the **EnumDisplayDevicesA** API but for an unknown reason I can't get the current display resolution for the device **\\.\DISPLAY2** using the **EnumDisplayDevicesA** API. 
Here is the code:

```
displays = 0;
result = 1;

for (index = 0; result != 0; index++)
{
    devices[index].cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICEA);
    result = EnumDisplayDevicesA(NULL, index, &(devices[displays] ), 0);

    if (result == 0)
    {
            break;
    }

    settings[index].dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODEA);
    mode = 0;

    // Collect the settings
    while(EnumDisplaySettingsA(devices[index].DeviceName, mode, (DEVMODEA *)&(settings[displays] ) ) )
    {
        mode++;
    };

    // Read the current settings
    result = EnumDisplaySettingsA(devices[index].DeviceName, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, (DEVMODEA *)&(settings[displays] ) );

    if (result != 0)
    {
        displays++;
    }
    else 
    {
        result = GetLastError();
        printf("Error while readind display settings %d\n", result);

        //Skip this device
        result = 1;
    }
}
```

Note that this code works flawlessly on some computers while on computers with multiple video cards it fails. For examle it fails on a laptop with an Intel HD Graphicw 630 + Nvidia Quadro M1200 where the active displays are the main laptop display and an exteral display attached through either the HDMI or DP port). More precisely on these computers I can get the correct resolution for the first display device (\\.\DISPLAY1) but on the second display device (\\.\DISPLAY2) the returned width and height is 0.

The **EnumDisplaySettingsA** API just return 0 as well as the **GetLastError** API.

What does  devices represent ? Are they a monitor attached to a single video card or are they just monitors attached to whatever video card ?

*NOTE:* Using **EnumDisplayMonitors** I can get the resolution of all monitors while **EnumDisplaySettingsA** fails.

Comment: Have you tried `if( result != 0 )` instead of `if( result == 1 )` ?  According to the documentation, the result is not 0 vs. 1, it is 0 on failure, and *non-zero* on success.

Comment: Also, `result` must be correctly initialized before the main `for` loop, are you sure you initialize it?  (Better yet, how about skipping the condition check in the main `for` loop?)

Comment: Hardware issue.  These are the kind of laptops that let you choose which adapter you want to use the drive the main LCD panel.  Meant as a battery-saving feature, the inactive adapter gets physically powered down.

Comment: @MikeNakis I see your point but the suggested change doesn't solve the problem. When I debug the code I see that __EnumDisplaySettingsA__ returns 0 in both the while loop (__mode__ is never incremented) and in the second call with __ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS__. Moreover __result__ is set to 1 before the loop. I updated the code.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't get your point. The monitor is active and powered on while the code is running. Furthermore I tried different monitors and the problem is always the same. It seems like to be related to the video card rather than the monitor.

Comment: Why do you have to cast a `DEVMODE` to `DEVMODEA` ?  I look at their documentation, and they do not appear to be interchangeable, because one has `wchar_t` fields, the other has `BYTE` fields.

Comment: Following up Mike's comment, `DEVMODE` is a macro defined as `DEVMODEW` if compiled as Unicode, or `DEVMODEA` if compiled as ANSI. The same is true for `DISPLAY_DEVICE`, `EnumDisplaySettings`, etc. It seems you are compiling as Unicode and mixing ANSI functions/structures. Don't use `****A` functions/structures. Also, are you sure you don't want `EnumDisplayMonitors`? That will give you monitor resolutions and positions.

Comment: One classic mistake that can cause very strange results is to type out the string literal incorrectly as `"\\.\DISPLAY2"` rather than `"\\\\.\\DISPLAY2"`. Windows will probably recognize `\.` just fine, and with some bad luck `\D` would have been a valid C escape sequence.

Comment: @MikeNakis The project built using an nmake file a no unicode flag is supplied at compilation time. So I need to use the ASCII version and all structures are declared as DEVMODEA. I wrongly used DEVMODE in the __sizeof__ invocation. Good catch. I also renamed all DISPLAY_DEVICE statements to DISPLAY_DEVICEA. Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani See my previous comment above. I already use EnumDisplayMonitors without problems but I need to save the current screen settings, make some changes using the __ChangeDisplaySettingsExA__ API and then restore the original settings using the same API. This API needs an initialized DEVMODEA structure. This is why I used the __EnumDisplaySettingsA__ API

Comment: What I am trying to say, and what Barmak Shemirani is also saying above, is that you should be not need to use the `DEVMODEA` at all.  If you are compiling right, then `DEVMODE` should map to `DEVMODEA`, and everything should compile and it should work correctly.  If it doesn't compile, then there is something wrong with the way you are compiling, and `DEVMODE` in fact compiles as something different from `DEVMODEA`, in which case you have to cast, but casting between them when they are not the same is guaranteed to result in miserable failure.

Comment: @Lundin As you can see the display names are read using the __EnumDisplayDevicesA__ API. So they can't be bad formatted.

Comment: @MikeNakis I see your point but even if I will compile with the Unicode flag in future I don't think that display names would benefit from wide-character adoption. Since all settings and device strings are ASCII I prefer using explicitly the ASCII methods and types.

Comment: We are talking past each other.  I am not saying you should compile either in Unicode or in ANSI.  Use whatever you want.  And change it in the future as much as you want.  What I am saying is that if you have to reference any of the `...A` or `...W` structures or functions, then you are doing something wrong.   If you use the correct compiler options then you should never need to reference those, and if you do reference them, and you receive type mismatch errors, and you cast those errors away, then you are deliberately setting yourself up for disappointment.

Comment: Now, if you specifically want to ***mix*** character-type-specific code with character-type-agnostic code, then this is an entirely different issue.  If you want to do that, then you need to be using the `...A` (or the `...W`) functions and structures in those particular places where you want something other than what your compiler options are mainly targeting.

Comment: But even in that case, you ***still*** cannot mix the two.  You have to keep all the character-type-agnostic stuff completely separate from the character-type-specific stuff. You cannot simply cast a character-type-specific structure to a character-type-agnostic structure just because your code would not compile otherwise.

Comment: "C is not javascript."

Comment: @MikeNakis I think the same plus I hate Javascript. Going back to the problem: I appreciate your suggestions but this is not a compilation problem and I know what casting to an incompatible type means. Anyway I'm using the ASCII version of functions and types on all code. The code is compiling but not working. That's the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be that more than two devices can be obtained by iterating over EnumDisplayDevices?
For me there were like 7 \.\DISPLAYX entries, even though I only have the Laptop Display and two external Monitors.
And when calling EnumDisplaySettings with a not connected Display, the results are like in your case 0. For me DISPLAY1, DISPLAY4 and DISPLAY5 were the ones I needed to use.

Comment: Actually I made a mistake.  I used __index__ also for initializing the structure and passing the device name to EnumDisplaySettingsA. I should have used the __displays__ variable instead.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> (DEVMODEA*)&(settings[displays])
> ```

The fact that you are using a cast suggests `settings` is defined incorrectly, and cast is used to hide the problem. If you have declared, for example, `DEVMODEA *settings = malloc(count * sizeof(DEVMODEA))` then casting should not be necessary.

You should simply use Unicode functions as recommended by Microsoft. If you need to print ANSI, then use `WideCharToMultiByte` to convert Unicode to ANSI.

Moreover, you are overwriting `settings[index]` in the code below:

> ```
> while(EnumDisplaySettingsA(devices[index].DeviceName, mode, (DEVMODEA *)&(settings[displays] ) ) )
>     mode++;
> result = EnumDisplaySettingsA(devices[index].DeviceName, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, (DEVMODEA *)&(settings[displays] ) );
> ```

Note that the second call to `EnumDisplaySettingsA` uses `ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS`, this call will never fail and may cause problems in your loop. It will also overwrite the previous value for `settings[displays]`

Try the code below to see if there is a difference.

```
int main()
{
    DISPLAY_DEVICE device = { 0 };
    device.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);
    for(int index = 0;; index++)
    {
        if(!EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, index, &device, EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME))
            break;

#ifdef UNICODE
        wprintf(L"%s\n", device.DeviceName);
#else
        printf("%s\n", device.DeviceName);
#endif

        DEVMODE devmode = { 0 };
        devmode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
        for(int modes = 0;; modes++)
        {
            if(!EnumDisplaySettings(device.DeviceName, modes, &devmode))
                break;
            printf("%d %d %d\n", 
                devmode.dmPelsWidth, 
                devmode.dmPelsHeight,
                devmode.dmDisplayFrequency);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Or read current resolution for each monitor

```
int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    DISPLAY_DEVICE temp = { 0 };
    temp.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);
    while(EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, count, &temp, EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME))
        count++;
    DEVMODE *settings = malloc(count * sizeof(DEVMODE));
    DISPLAY_DEVICE *devices = malloc(count * sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE));

    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
    {
        memset(&devices[index], 0, sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE));
        memset(&settings[index], 0, sizeof(DEVMODE));
        devices[index].cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);
        settings[index].dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
        if(!EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, index, &devices[index], EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME))
            break;
        if(!EnumDisplaySettings(devices[index].DeviceName, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &settings[index]))
            break;
    }

    for(int index = 0; index < count; index++)
    {
#ifdef UNICODE
        wprintf(L"%s ", devices[index].DeviceName);
#else
        printf("%s ",  devices[index].DeviceName);
#endif
        printf("%d %d %d\n", 
            settings[index].dmPelsWidth,
            settings[index].dmPelsHeight,
            settings[index].dmDisplayFrequency);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ___Note that the second call to EnumDisplaySettingsA uses ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, this call will never fail and may cause problems in your loop. It will also overwrite the previous value for settings[displays]___ . This is also intentional. The doc recommend to call EnumDisplaySettings until the returned value is 0. This should initialize all the modes then I can get the current one. Furthermore the function fails (return value = 0) even with ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS as mode.

Comment: That's not how you initialize a structure. I have no idea what your goal is if you have those loops intentionally. You are not following the documentation. The docs do say to call `EnumDisplaySettings` until it fails, as shown in the code I suggested, not the way you wrote in the question.

Comment: I only want the current resolution for each monitor not all available modes for each monitor. So your code doens't suit me. Maybe I can avoid the while loop in my code and just make the first call with modes = 0 but that's not the problem.

Comment: In that case you only need to call `EnumDisplaySettings` once. The docs say call it multiple times only if you enumerate all the resolutions. See edit.

Comment: No you still need to call __EnumDisplaySettings__ with 0 as mode parameter the first time. Read the doc. This is needed to cache the settings.

Comment: Your are counting the displays which is ok but this doesn't insure you that the active screens has an index between 0 and count -1. You can have 3 devices and only the device 3 is active. In your case the structure at index 0 would be selected which is wrong. Also you don't need another loop for printing the results. You can print them in the loop above.

Comment: I'm not here to arguing. That is a waste of time. This is what the doc says: ___When you call EnumDisplaySettings with iModeNum set to zero, the operating system initializes and caches information about the display device. When you call EnumDisplaySettings with iModeNum set to a nonzero value, the function returns the information that was cached the last time the function was called with iModeNum set to zero.___ Since ENUM_CURRENT_SETTING is a nonzero value I believe that this applies to that case too.

Comment: See this example [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/DX11VideoRenderer/cpp/display.cpp), the author appears to be a Microsoft programmer, it just calls `EnumDisplaySettings` once. You can call that function with zero parameter if you like, it's not going to hurt, but it's not necessary. The current settings is already cached somewhere, same with registry settings.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not related to the windows API nor related to the casting. The casting is not needed so I removed it.
This is caused by a wrong usage of the variables in the code. As I said I only want the current resolution of each monitor and on every index of both `devices` and `settings` structures I only want data related to active displays. This is ensured by the usage of the `displays` variable which is only incremented when the device has readable settings. Conversely the `index` variable should be incremented to each loop until the `EnumEnumDisplayDevicesA` fails.

Unfortunately I used `index` also for initializing the structure and passing the device name to `EnumDisplaySettingsA`. My bad. So I was filling the devices structure using the `devices[displays]` statement while the structure passed to `EnumDisplaySettingsA` was `devices[index]`. In other words the incorrect name was passed to the API ant this is the reason while it was failing. On some computers it was working because the active monitor were the first but as soon as the DISPLAY1 or DISPALY2 was not connected the application would behave incorrectly.

This is the correct code:

```
displays = 0;
result = 1;

for (index = 0; result != 0; index++)
{
    devices[displays].cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICEA);
    result = EnumDisplayDevicesA(NULL, index, &(devices[displays] ), 0);

    if (result == 0)
    {
            break;
    }

    settings[displays].dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODEA);
    mode = 0;

    // Cache the settings
    EnumDisplaySettingsA(devices[displays].DeviceName, 0, &(settings[displays] ) ) 

    // Read the current settings
    result = EnumDisplaySettingsA(devices[displays].DeviceName, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &(settings[displays] ) );

    if (result != 0)
    {
        displays++;
    }
    else 
    {
        result = GetLastError();
        printf("Error while readind display settings %d\n", result);

        //Skip this device
        result = 1;
    }
```

Comment: This should work if you are only interested in the current settings. It should be the same result as your original code, or same as my code, unless `EnumDisplaySettingsA(... ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS ...)` fails at least once. Can you confirm that `EnumDisplaySettingsA(... ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS ...)` has at least one failure?

Comment: I specified from the beginning that I was interested in the current resolution for each monitor. The result of this code is different. This is working and the former code was failing. The reason is specified in my answer above. The EnumDisplaySettingsA API fails if the passed DeviceName is incorrect (that was my problem) or if the device doesn't have an active monitor plugged in (This might be a disconnected video port). As specified in the @Detlf 's answer the device returned by EnumDisplayDevicesA are more than the active devices.